# How to select the smallest element that contains text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I'm using Rails 5 with Nokogiri.  How do I select the smallest element that contains text?

I have this element on my page:

```
<td class="style35" style="font-size: medium; border: thin solid #000000">
                        Location</td>
```

and I thought I could select it using:

```
doc.at('td:contains("Location")')
```

Instead, a wrapping td that contains the table that contains this element is selected:

```
<td><span class="myClass"><table> ....
```

What is the proper way to write an expression that selects the smallest (most minimal?) element that contains the text I want?

Comment: It's not "NOkogiri", It's "Nokogiri", "seleted" is "selected", "teh" is "the", "ocntains" is "contains". Grammar and spelling are important on SO. Your question is the beginning of a reference page and the answers are the solutions to the problem, like a page in an encyclopedia or a cookbook.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". You need to give us the smallest example of HTML that will demonstrate the problem, in one piece, not in separated chunks. Don't make us reconstruct it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [`at`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#at-instance_method) method it will only return the first result.

The [`css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#css-instance_method) method will return all the elements matching the CSS selector, both the correct `td` element, and the `td` element wrapping around the whole table.

If you use something like this, it will find all the `td` tags, containing the word `Location`, then it will store the elements that is not wrapped around another td tag in an array:

```
td_with_no_child_and_have_location = []

doc.css("td:contains('Location')").each do |td_element| 
    if td_element.css("td").empty? 
        td_with_no_child_and_have_location << td_element
    end
end

first_td = td_with_no_child_and_have_location.first
```

Comment: I'm not explaning myself well.  I don't want the TD with the least HTML, I want the TD that has no other child TD's and whose text contains the word "Location".

Comment: I updated my answer, so that it stores an array of the elements that fit your condition. Then you can use the first element of that array, if you know that your element will always be the first.

Comment: Thanks for this update.  Is there any way to write a CSS selector that does in one line what you did with the loop?

Comment: Yes, you could use `doc.css("td td:contains('Location')")`, however that will only make sure that it is the second td tag, not necessary the last in a bigger tree. If you only have one table inside the original table, that would work.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help you if you don't supply us with the minimum HTML. I tried recreating it but YMMV:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html><body><table><tr>
<td><span class="myClass"><table><tr>
      <td class="style35" style="font-size: medium; border: thin solid #000000">
        Location</td>
</tr></table></td></tr></table></html>
EOT
doc.at('.myClass td.style35').text # => "\n        Location"
```

If the tag you want is embedded in another table, then take advantage of some of the other characteristics to help you navigate, such as the class information.

Using `at` should help in this case because typically the title of a table would be in the first row which would contain the first cell. `at` is the equivalent of `search('some selector').first`.

The above selector could even be written as `.myCLass .style35` or `td td` which would find the td inside another td. Combine that with `at` and you'd get the first such occurrence:

```
doc.at('.myClass td.style35').text # => "\n        Location"
doc.at('.myClass .style35').text # => "\n        Location"
doc.at('td td').text # => "\n        Location"
```

Comment: I'm looking for somethign a little more general.  The TD will not always have "myClass" as a class.  I'm looking for the TD with that contains the given text with no other TDs within it.

Comment: You need to provide more information in your question then. It's extremely broad as is and doesn't meet the guidelines in "[mcve]". We can't vote on it because you have a bounty. If you're trying to write a generic "always find a title" cell without knowing beforehand what that title or the document's structure is, you're going to have a hard time.

Answer (score -1):

Pick all `td` elements, sort by the content length and pick the first element. Change the selector as you may wish. Sort is ascending by default. So you get the smallest elements first.

```
doc.css('td').sort_by do |td_element|
  l.text.length
end.first
```

Comment: YOu're logic doesn't work for my case, tho.  The expression, "doc.at('td:contains("Location")'" is only returning a single element.  Running "doc.at('td:contains("Location")').at('td:contains("Location")')" gets me the element I want for this specific case, but in general I won't know how many levels to drill down to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: This isn't good logic. Subsequent cells could contain shorter strings than the desired one. Also, your example code isn't valid. I'd recommend testing your code against sample HTML and show your results.